# Is it possible to get source code when making a request with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There's an element on the website that I am trying to mess around with, but getting to that element is hard, because the ID of it changes every time you visit the page.

So, I somehow want to get source code whenever selenium enters the website and use regex to get the correct ID of that element.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or any ideas how to get the wanted element in another way?

```
<select role="listbox" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="label-agreement" class="x-form-text x-form-field " name="agreement" tabindex="0" id="tts-6535350604697758">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">I agree</option>
  <option value="2">I don't agree</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Something seems off. The point of an ID is to identify an element; if the identity keeps changing, what use is it?

Comment: No idea.
`<select role="listbox" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="label-agreement" class="x-form-text x-form-field   " name="agreement" tabindex="0" id="tts-6535350604697758"><option value=""></option><option value="1">I agree</option><option value="2">I don't agree</option></select>`

The tts ID changes numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` attribute, it seem unique enough

```
driver.find_element_by_name('agreement')
```

Or by `aria-labelledby` attribute

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-labelledby="label-agreement"]')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Luckily there are no other elements by that name on the page.